# Center flexbox items on either side of the page?

Tags: css, flexbox

[Footer for restaurant page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cUHC.png)

For my project im recreating this basic restaurant home page and the only part I have left is the footer. In my course we only know the most basic css and flexbox so I want to keep my solution in that area, but my thought process right now is splitting the footer in half and then using justify-content: center to center the Join our mailing list! on the left half of the footer and the navigation links on the right side of the footer. Is this possible?

I've tried using widths, using divs of left-footer and right-footer and using display flex on both, using margins and padding to manually push one side to the other, but it never lined up correctly.

Comment: flex-grow:2 then flex-grow:1 for the next, should be a start with flex ...

Comment: Apart from the image, can you also share a link to the restaurant page, as well as show us your current progress on the footer? That way it may be easier to help, and maybe even give feedback to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested flexboxes.

1. One on the `footer`, so you can use `justify-content: space-between;` to separate its content left and right
2. Another one on the `nav`, so you can use `gap: 1em;` to specify the space between the menu items.

Like this:

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: cyan;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div>
    <input placeholder="email address">
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <a href="">Menu1</a>
    <a href="">Menu2</a>
    <a href="">Menu3</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```